# Can't calculate avarage properly in R

Tags: r, mean

I have this table and I want to calculate avarage of the all mean values in `CHOR1`, `CHOR2` and `KONTROLA`:

```
      grupa           plcie    dane  wiek     hsCRP     ERY    PLT      HGB      HCT     MCHC       MON     LEU
1     CHOR1   liczba kobiet     min 17.00  0.487607  3.5300 128.00  9.50490 0.280000 32.55560 0.4800000  6.7900
2     CHOR1              14 mediana 29.00  3.966460  4.2000 217.00 12.40470 0.363000 35.04710 0.7600000 11.6600
3     CHOR1 liczba mezczyzn    mean 29.56  6.103022  5.3628 225.28 12.40173 0.363560 35.12882 0.8578811 12.0220
4     CHOR1              11     max 43.00 42.649900 33.0000 336.00 14.49900 0.405000 36.87420 1.5200000 16.8100
5     CHOR2   liczba kobiet     min 21.00  0.335089  3.2500  91.00  9.82710 0.042300 32.88780 0.1400000  7.9500
6     CHOR2              12 mediana 30.00  3.445460  4.2700 195.00 12.56580 0.360000 35.54540 0.6600000 12.0000
7     CHOR2 liczba mezczyzn    mean 30.04  5.536029  4.1976 209.12 12.80616 0.345972 35.55204 0.9528000 12.0376
8     CHOR2              13     max 42.00 19.212400  5.0400 456.00 22.23180 0.412000 38.86740 7.0000000 16.5900
9  KONTROLA   liczba kobiet     min 23.00  0.758440  3.0900 147.00  9.50490 0.279000 32.05730 0.3500000  4.8300
10 KONTROLA              14 mediana 32.00  4.220370  3.9800 214.00 11.43810 0.339000 34.54880 0.7600000 10.6800
11 KONTROLA liczba mezczyzn    mean 32.32  5.295149  4.0132 225.88 11.29980 0.337560 34.40263 0.7604000 11.3604
12 KONTROLA              11     max 48.00 14.395100  5.0500 434.00 13.21020 0.389000 36.04370 1.2500000 17.4600
```

I am using this function to calculate avarage of `min`, `median`, `max`, and `mean`
(`charakterystyka_numeric` is the same table, but with only numerical columns):

```
for(j in 1:nr_kolumn){
  
    for(p in 1:liczba_grup){
      minimum_srednia <- minimum_srednia + strtoi(charakterystyka_numeric[(p+((p*3)-3)), j])
      mediana_srednia <- mediana_srednia + strtoi(charakterystyka_numeric[((p*2)+((p*2)-2)), j])
      mean_srednia <- mean_srednia + strtoi(charakterystyka_numeric[((p*3)+(p-1)), j])
      print(charakterystyka_numeric[((p*3)+(p-1)), j])
      print(mean_srednia)
      max_srednia <- max_srednia + strtoi(charakterystyka_numeric[(p*4), j])
      print(mean_srednia)
    }
    minimum_srednia <- minimum_srednia/liczba_grup
    mediana_srednia <- mediana_srednia/liczba_grup
    mean_srednia <- mean_srednia/liczba_grup
    max_srednia <- max_srednia/liczba_grup
```

Everything works properly except `mean_srednia` it returns `NA` as the result.

Comment: Your question is not reproducible.  Where are `nr_kolumn`, liczba_group` and many more items defined?  I think a simple ytidyverse solution would use `summarise(across(...), ...)` and remove many, if not all, of the complexities in your attempt.  Please post your ample data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, something like

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(grupa) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      where(is.numeric), 
      list("mean"=mean, "min"=min, "max"=max, "median"=median), 
      na.rm=TRUE
    )
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 41
  grupa    m_mean m_min m_max m_median wiek_mean wiek_min wiek_max wiek_median hsCRP_mean hsCRP_min hsCRP_max hsCRP_median ERY_mean ERY_min ERY_max ERY_median PLT_mean PLT_min
  <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 CHOR1       2.5     1     4      2.5      29.6       17       43        29.3      13.3      0.488      42.6         5.03    11.5     3.53   33          4.78     227.     128
2 CHOR2       6.5     5     8      6.5      30.8       21       42        30.0       7.13     0.335      19.2         4.49     4.19    3.25    5.04       4.23     238.      91
3 KONTROLA   10.5     9    12     10.5      33.8       23       48        32.2       6.17     0.758      14.4         4.76     4.03    3.09    5.05       4.00     255.     147
# … with 22 more variables: PLT_max <dbl>, PLT_median <dbl>, HGB_mean <dbl>, HGB_min <dbl>, HGB_max <dbl>, HGB_median <dbl>, HCT_mean <dbl>, HCT_min <dbl>, HCT_max <dbl>,
#   HCT_median <dbl>, MCHC_mean <dbl>, MCHC_min <dbl>, MCHC_max <dbl>, MCHC_median <dbl>, MON_mean <dbl>, MON_min <dbl>, MON_max <dbl>, MON_median <dbl>, LEU_mean <dbl>,
#   LEU_min <dbl>, LEU_max <dbl>, LEU_median <dbl>
```

Should give you close to what you want.

I suspect your problem with `mean_srednia` is due to missing values, but since you haven't shown us that column, I can't be sure.  If I am correct, the `na.rm=FALSE` in my solution should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a short base R approach, you might try `aggregate()` to calc. the means:

```r
# data 
df <- data.frame(grupa = as.factor(c(rep("C", 5), rep("K", 5))),
                 V1 = rnorm(10),
                 V2 = rnorm(10))
# approach
aggregate(.~grupa, data = df, mean)
#>   grupa         V1         V2
#> 1     C -0.1779009 -0.1893905
#> 2     K  0.3261067  0.2520248
```

Replace `mean` by `min` etc. Note, the toy data I am using has only two levels. The approach, of course, works for several levels of variable `grupa`.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>